# Is there a solid .Net wrapper for the Managed Wifi Win32 API?

Tags: c#, .net, wrapper, native, wifi

Has anyone developed (either as open source or as a reasonably-priced commercial offering) a .Net implementation of the Win32 Native Wifi API?    Or does anyone here know of such a thing?

I've done about an hour and a half of spelunking on Google, MSDN, pinvoke.net and here, and haven't found anything.   If I've missed something obvious, I apologize!

We're on a tight deadline, I know little about Wifi, and I need to get something running quickly.   I can either cut 'n' paste from pinvoke.net, or write a .Net wrapper class in C++, but I'd prefer not to spend the time doing that, if possible.

What we need to do is poll continuously for the presence of a particular SSID;  when it's seen, connect immediately and report to the client, who can then send some socket and/or SOAP messages, then advise us when it's safe to disconnect.    We need to be able to report the signal strength to the client, as well ... it needs to make intelligent decisions about using Wifi vs. other communication modes available to it.   For the first iteration, this can be unsecured, but we'll probably want to add the ability to specify a WEP key in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the network management APIs that are wrapped up in the [Code Pack](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/WindowsAPICodePack) help you? I believe you can get a .NET event when various things happen, and surely the availability of a specific SSID counts. I haven't done more than run the demo myself, but take a look. I think you'll like the license terms also - you're allowed to incorporate the library into your code.

**UPDATE**:

The given API, unfortunately, is no longer available. The link leads to the [MSDN archives pages](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/). Luckily, the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24081665/windows-api-code-pack-where-is-it) give links to the binaries of the aforementioned API.

Comment: Thanks, Kate!  It does look good.    We ended up using wlanapi via PInvoke() after all, for legacy XP support -- but I'm glad to know about this for the future...

Answer (score 1):

There is  [Managed Wifi API](http://managedwifi.codeplex.com/)   but I haven't used it myself so I can't comment about it.

Comment: Thanks, Giorgi.   I'd forgotten to mention that I'd found this solution.   It looks pretty good, but my customer wasn't comfortable with the LGPL restrictions.  Since this is for a shipping product with a tight beta deadline, they don't want to wait for a legal review on integrating the LGPL code.

But thanks for the tip -- it reminded me to go back and look at the source code, which is quite informative.

Anyone else?   A reasonable commercial product?